# Add custom plugins to wordpress kubernetes deployment

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy my wordpress site to a kubernetes cluster. I followed [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/#add-resource-configs-for-mysql-and-wordpress) guide and was able to successfully deploy a naked wordpress instance and access it via the url.

However, I can't seem to find out how to include my own custom wordpress content (basically include a local copy of the wp-content folder [including plugins, themes, and images]).

Without this, I have to manually install every plugin and re-upload all the media again manually every time i deploy, so I assume there is a way to do this with some kubernetes config that I just can't seem to find anywhere. Its also an immense amount of content so I don't really want to upload it all manually.

Fairly new to kubernetes so please excuse the question if its simple.

Followed this guide: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/#add-resource-configs-for-mysql-and-wordpress

Was hoping to find some instructions to add to the yaml like so:

```
include: my-local/wp-content
include: my-local/wp-includes
```

But through my digging I have not been able to find anything that solves what I am looking for.